# Double integral of acceleration in android accelerometer

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, gyroscope

Any code to find the distance from the android accelerometer. Some document defined to calulate double integral of acceleration to get the distance walked. Anyone please help me to find the double integral code in android with x,y and z acceleration values.